# React State in the course details page is setting values wrongly but the logged values after creating the course is correct

Tags: javascript, reactjs, solidity, react-state, react-state-management

So I have a form that is used to create a course/attendance:

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="w-full mt-[65px] flex flex-col gap-[30px]">
                        <div className="flex flex-wrap flex-col gap-[40px]">
                            <FormField 
                                labelName="Course Code *" 
                                placeholder="Enter the course code"
                                inputType="text"
                                value={form.courseCode}
                                handleChange={(e) => handleFormFieldChange('courseCode', e)}
                            />
                            <FormField 
                                labelName="Course Name"
                                placeholder="Provide the title of the Attendance"
                                inputType="text"
                                value={form.courseName}
                                handleChange={(e) => handleFormFieldChange('courseName', e)}
                            />
                            <FormField 
                                labelName="Lecturer"
                                placeholder="Provide lecturer's name"
                                inputType="text"
                                value={form.lecturer}
                                handleChange={(e) => handleFormFieldChange('lecturer', e)}
                            />
                            <FormField 
                                labelName="Attendance Description *"
                                placeholder="Provide a description of the Attendance"
                                isTextArea
                                value={form.description}
                                handleChange={(e) => handleFormFieldChange('description', e)}
                            />
                            <label className="font-epilogue font-medium text-[16px] text-white" htmlFor="department">Department *</label>
                                <select
                                    id="department"
                                    className="w-[300px] p-[8px] rounded-[5px] bg-[#3a3a43] text-white"
                                    value={form.department}
                                    onChange={(e) => handleFormFieldChange('department', e)}
                                >
                                    <option value="" disabled>Select Department</option>
                                    {departmentOptions.map((option) => (
                                        <option key={option} value={option}>
                                            {option}
                                        </option>
                                    ))}
                                </select>
                                <label className="font-epilogue font-medium text-[16px] text-white" htmlFor="department">Program Level *</label>
                                <select
                                    id="programLevel"
                                    className="w-[300px] p-[8px] rounded-[5px] bg-[#3a3a43] text-white"
                                    value={form.programLevel}
                                    onChange={(e) => handleFormFieldChange('programLevel', e)}
                                >
                                    <option value="" disabled>Select Program Level</option>
                                    {programOptions.map((option) => (
                                        <option key={option} value={option}>
                                            {option}
                                        </option>
                                    ))}
                                </select>
```

The handleFormFieldChange will then set the form using react state:

```
const[ form, setForm ] = useState({
        courseCode: '',
        lecturer: '',
        courseName:'',
        description:'',
        department:'',
        programLevel:'',
    });

const handleFormFieldChange =(fieldName, e) =>{
        let value = e.target.value;
        if (fieldName === 'courseName') {
            value = value.replace(/\//g, ''); 
        }
        setForm(({ ...form, [fieldName]: value }));
        console.log({ ...form, [fieldName]: value });
    }
```

Then call the createCourse from AttendanceContext:

```
import   { useStateContext } from '../../context/AttendanceContext.jsx';

const { createCourse } = useStateContext();

const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        try{
            setIsLoading(true);
            console.log({...form});
            await createCourse({...form});
            setIsLoading(false);
            //navigate('/attendance');
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("There was an error creating the course", error);
        }
    }
```

In AttendanceContext, createCourse would communicate with the solidity code. When I console.log the form after creating the course in the blockchain the console.log has the right values

```
const createCourse = async (form) => {
      const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(ethereum);
      const contract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, contractABI, provider);
      const address = window.ethereum.selectedAddress 
      try {
        if (!address) {
          await connect();
        }
    
        const signer = provider.getSigner();
        const contractWithSigner = contract.connect(signer);
        const data = await contractWithSigner.createCourse(
          form.courseCode,
          form.lecturer,
          form.courseName,
          form.description, 
          form.department,
          form.programLevel
          //startTime,
          //endTime,
        );
        console.log(form);
        console.log('Contract call success', data);

      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Contract call failure', error);
      }
    };
```

But when I open up the course details here:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useLocation, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import user from '../../images/user.png';
import { CountBox, CustomButton, Loading, Navbar, Footer } from '../../components/index.js';
import { useStateContext } from '../../context/AttendanceContext.jsx';
//import { daysLeft, convert } from '../../utils';
import AdminChecker from '../../utils/adminChecker.js';

const AdminCloseAttendanceDetails = () => {

    const { state } = useLocation();
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const { contract, address, closeCourse, getAttendees, getAttendeesCount, getLecturer } = useStateContext(); 
    const [ isLoading, setIsLoading ] = useState(false);
    const [ lecturer, setLecturer ] = useState('');
    //const[amount, setAmount]= useState('');
    const [ attendees, setAttendees ] = useState([]);
    const [ currentAttendeeCount, setCurrentAttendeeCount ] = useState([]);
    //const remainingTime = convert(state.endTime);
    const [ isLoadingAttendees, setIsLoadingAttendees ] = useState(true);
    

    const fetchAttendees = async () => {
      setIsLoadingAttendees(true);
      try{
        const lecturer = await getLecturer(state.pId);
        const data = await getAttendees(state.pId);
        console.log("State before setting lecturer:", state);
      console.log("Lecturer fetched:", lecturer);
        setAttendees(data);
        setLecturer(lecturer);
        const attendeeCount = await getAttendeesCount(state.pId);
        setCurrentAttendeeCount(attendeeCount);
      } finally {
        setIsLoadingAttendees(false);
      }
    }
```

The logs are giving me field entries in different fields and the programLevel field is just gone. the image field was should also be removed since I no longer use it but is still in the state

[The console log after creating the course](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ftPoe.png)

[The console log of the created the course at the details page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2b9T.png)

The expected outcome should be this:

[The console log after creating the course](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ftPoe.png)

But instead I am getting this:

[The console log of the created the course at the details page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2b9T.png)

Since the form is passed and used to create the course in the blockchain and I do get the logs of what I sent, why does it log wrongly in the details? And this results in me not being able to use the fields.